# Using the lock statement

Tags: c#, multithreading, bitmap, locking, save

I have a Bitmap that I'm trying to save and I keep getting the "Object is currently in use elsewhere" error. Now I know GDI+ sucks with threading and that I'm supposed to use the `lock{}` statement but it's not working. My code is below, what am I doing incorrectly?

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap();

lock (bitmap)
{
    bitmap.Save([filepath], ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should lock other dummy object:

```
var objectForLock = new object()

lock (objectForLock)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap();
    bitmap.Save([filepath], ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Not sure if that's your problem, but that's the way `lock` works in .Net.

Comment: @svick its a bad practice because what if something else tries to lock on your instance?

Comment: @DanielA.White. And with `BitMap`, it does... `:)`

Comment: What would I use in place of a Bitmap? I'm trying this lock thing and I just don't seem to have any luck.

Answer (score 3):

You should not lock on the object you are trying to lock. You should create a new reference and lock on that instead.

```
object bitmapLock = new object();
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap();

lock (bitmapLock)
{
    bitmap.Save([filepath], ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

The bitmap might lock in different places that are beyond your control.

Read about the `lock` statement here.

**Edit** you might have to modify the bitmap on the thread that it was created.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should lock synchronize before you initialize the Bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have lock around all operations, not just Save. Locking for just save will not block other threads from manipulating the Bitmap.

Note that it is better to lock on separate object as everyone recommends.

```
// class member (or even static) 
private object bitmapLock = new object();

// function 1
lock (bitmapLock)
{
    bitmap.Save([filepath], ImageFormat.Png);
}

// function 2
lock (bitmapLock)
{
   // Draw bitmap
}
```

Comment: I think this may be where I'm tripped up at. What if the same bitmap is being accessed by multiple classes. How can I get it to lock on the same object?

Comment: Cheat way to do it to make the object to lock on to be `public static` somewhere, could be a good start to see if code actually works when all accesses to the bitmap are protected with the the same lock. Note that @Daniel A. White could be right about need to marshal access to the bitmap to original thread which would mean that locking not going to help you... Later you can refactor your code so you make locking object accessible where it is needed (maybe by wrapping all operations).